# Android Segmented Control Design

Tags: android, button

How to change text color of Segmented Controls (if not selected), see below images:

I am getting like this (`text` in **white** color):

[image]

And want to design this (`text` in **blue** color):

[image]

```
Why i am getting space between 3 and 4 button ?
```

**XML:**

```
  <com.om.go.widget.SegmentedButton
      android:id="@+id/segmented"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      myapp:gradientColorOnStart="#ffffff"
      myapp:gradientColorOnEnd="#ffffff"
      myapp:gradientColorOffStart="#016de3"
      myapp:gradientColorOffEnd="#016de3"         
      myapp:textStyle="@style/TextViewStyleHeaderButtonBlue"
      myapp:strokeColor="#016de3"
      myapp:strokeWidth="1dip"
      myapp:cornerRadius="4dip"
      myapp:btnPaddingTop="7dip"
      myapp:btnPaddingBottom="7dip"
      />
```

**SegmentedButton.java:-**

```
public class SegmentedButton extends LinearLayout {

    private StateListDrawable mBgLeftOn;
    private StateListDrawable mBgRightOn;
    private StateListDrawable mBgCenterOn;
    private StateListDrawable mBgLeftOff;
    private StateListDrawable mBgRightOff;
    private StateListDrawable mBgCenterOff;
    private int mSelectedButtonIndex = 0;

    private List<String> mButtonTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int mColorOnStart;
    private int mColorOnEnd;
    private int mColorOffStart;
    private int mColorOffEnd;
    private int mColorSelectedStart;
    private int mColorSelectedEnd;
    private int mColorStroke;
    private int mStrokeWidth;
    private int mCornerRadius;
    private int mTextStyle;
    private int mBtnPaddingTop;
    private int mBtnPaddingBottom;

    private OnClickListenerSegmentedButton mOnClickListenerExternal;


    public SegmentedButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SegmentedButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SegmentedButton, 0, 0);

        CharSequence btnText1 = a.getString(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_btnText1);
        CharSequence btnText2 = a.getString(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_btnText2);
        if (btnText1 != null) {
            mButtonTitles.add(btnText1.toString());
        }
        if (btnText2 != null) {
            mButtonTitles.add(btnText2.toString());
        }

        mColorOnStart = a.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_gradientColorOnStart, 0xFF0000);
        mColorOnEnd = a.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_gradientColorOnEnd, 0xFF0000);
        mColorOffStart = a.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_gradientColorOffStart, 0xFF0000);
        mColorOffEnd = a.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_gradientColorOffEnd, 0xFF0000);
        mColorStroke = a.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_strokeColor, 0xFF0000);
        mColorSelectedEnd = a.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_gradientColorSelectedEnd, 0xFF0000);
        mColorSelectedStart = a.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_gradientColorSelectedStart, 0xFF0000);
        mStrokeWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_strokeWidth, 1);
        mCornerRadius = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_cornerRadius, 4);
        mTextStyle = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_textStyle, -1);
        mBtnPaddingTop = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_btnPaddingTop, 0);
        mBtnPaddingBottom = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SegmentedButton_btnPaddingBottom, 0);


        a.recycle();

        buildDrawables(mColorOnStart, mColorOnEnd, mColorOffStart, mColorOffEnd, 
                mColorSelectedStart, mColorSelectedEnd, mCornerRadius, mColorStroke, 
                mStrokeWidth);

        if (mButtonTitles.size() > 0) {
            _addButtons(new String[mButtonTitles.size()]);
        }
    }

    public void clearButtons() {
        removeAllViews();
    }

    public void addButtons(String ... titles) {
        _addButtons(titles);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void _addButtons(String[] titles) {

        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {

            Button button = new Button(getContext());
            button.setText(titles[i]);
            button.setTag(new Integer(i));
            button.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            if (mTextStyle != -1) {
                button.setTextAppearance(getContext(), mTextStyle);
            }

            if (titles.length == 1) {
                // Don't use a segmented button with one button.
                return;
            } else if (titles.length == 2) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    button.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgLeftOff);
                } else {
                    button.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgRightOn);
                }
            } else {
                if (i == 0) {
                    button.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgLeftOff);
                } else if (i == titles.length-1) {
                    button.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgRightOn);
                } else {
                    button.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgCenterOn);
                }
            }
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = 
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        0, 
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        1);
            addView(button, llp);
            button.setPadding(0, mBtnPaddingTop, 0, mBtnPaddingBottom);
        }
    }

    private void buildDrawables(int colorOnStart,
                                int colorOnEnd,
                                int colorOffStart,
                                int colorOffEnd,
                                int colorSelectedStart,
                                int colorSelectedEnd,
                                float crad,
                                int strokeColor,
                                int strokeWidth) 
    {
        // top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left
        float[] radiiLeft = new float[] {
            crad, crad, 0, 0, 0, 0, crad, crad        
        };
        float[] radiiRight = new float[] {
            0, 0, crad, crad, crad, crad, 0, 0        
        };
        float[] radiiCenter = new float[] {
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0        
        };

        GradientDrawable leftOn = buildGradientDrawable(colorOnStart, colorOnEnd, strokeWidth, strokeColor);
        leftOn.setCornerRadii(radiiLeft);
        GradientDrawable leftOff = buildGradientDrawable(colorOffStart, colorOffEnd, strokeWidth, strokeColor);
        leftOff.setCornerRadii(radiiLeft);
        GradientDrawable leftSelected = buildGradientDrawable(colorSelectedStart, colorSelectedEnd, strokeWidth, strokeColor);
        leftSelected.setCornerRadii(radiiLeft);

        GradientDrawable rightOn = buildGradientDrawable(colorOnStart, colorOnEnd, strokeWidth, strokeColor);
        rightOn.setCornerRadii(radiiRight);
        GradientDrawable rightOff = buildGradientDrawable(colorOffStart, colorOffEnd, strokeWidth, strokeColor);
        rightOff.setCornerRadii(radiiRight);
        GradientDrawable rightSelected = buildGradientDrawable(colorSelectedStart, colorSelectedEnd, strokeWidth, strokeColor);
        rightSelected.setCornerRadii(radiiRight);

        GradientDrawable centerOn = buildGradientDrawable(colorOnStart, colorOnEnd, strokeWidth, strokeColor);
        centerOn.setCornerRadii(radiiCenter);
        GradientDrawable centerOff = buildGradientDrawable(colorOffStart, colorOffEnd, strokeWidth, strokeColor);
        centerOff.setCornerRadii(radiiCenter);
        GradientDrawable centerSelected = buildGradientDrawable(colorSelectedStart, colorSelectedEnd, strokeWidth, strokeColor);
        centerSelected.setCornerRadii(radiiCenter);

        List<int[]> onStates = buildOnStates();
        List<int[]> offStates = buildOffStates();

        mBgLeftOn = new StateListDrawable();
        mBgRightOn = new StateListDrawable();
        mBgCenterOn = new StateListDrawable();
        mBgLeftOff = new StateListDrawable();
        mBgRightOff = new StateListDrawable();
        mBgCenterOff = new StateListDrawable();
        for (int[] it : onStates) {
            mBgLeftOn.addState(it, leftSelected);
            mBgRightOn.addState(it, rightSelected);
            mBgCenterOn.addState(it, centerSelected);
            mBgLeftOff.addState(it, leftSelected);
            mBgRightOff.addState(it, rightSelected);
            mBgCenterOff.addState(it, centerSelected);
        }
        for (int[] it : offStates) {
            mBgLeftOn.addState(it, leftOn);
            mBgRightOn.addState(it, rightOn);
            mBgCenterOn.addState(it, centerOn);
            mBgLeftOff.addState(it, leftOff);
            mBgRightOff.addState(it, rightOff);
            mBgCenterOff.addState(it, centerOff);
        }
    }

    private List<int[]> buildOnStates() {
        List<int[]> res = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        res.add(new int[] { 
            android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_enabled});
        res.add(new int[] { 
                android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_selected, android.R.attr.state_enabled});
        res.add(new int[] { 
                android.R.attr.state_pressed});
        return res;
    }

    private List<int[]> buildOffStates() {
        List<int[]> res = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        res.add(new int[] { 
            android.R.attr.state_enabled});
        res.add(new int[] { 
                android.R.attr.state_selected, android.R.attr.state_enabled});
        return res;
    }

    private GradientDrawable buildGradientDrawable(int colorStart, int colorEnd, int strokeWidth, int strokeColor) {
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                new int[] { colorStart, colorEnd });
        gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        gd.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor);
        return gd;
    }

    private OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button btnNext = (Button)v;
            int btnNextIndex = ((Integer)btnNext.getTag()).intValue();
            if (btnNextIndex == mSelectedButtonIndex) {
                return;
            }

            handleStateChange(mSelectedButtonIndex, btnNextIndex);

            if (mOnClickListenerExternal != null) {
                mOnClickListenerExternal.onClick(mSelectedButtonIndex);
            }
        }
    };

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void handleStateChange(int btnLastIndex, int btnNextIndex) {
        int count = getChildCount();
        Button btnLast = (Button)getChildAt(btnLastIndex);
        Button btnNext = (Button)getChildAt(btnNextIndex);

        if (count < 3) {
            if (btnLastIndex == 0) {
                btnLast.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgLeftOn);
            } else {
                btnLast.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgRightOn);
            }
            if (btnNextIndex == 0) {
                btnNext.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgLeftOff);
            } else {
                btnNext.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgRightOff);
            }
        } else {
            if (btnLastIndex == 0) {
                btnLast.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgLeftOn);
            } else if (btnLastIndex == count-1) {
                btnLast.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgRightOn);
            } else {
                btnLast.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgCenterOn);
            }

            if (btnNextIndex == 0) {
                btnNext.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgLeftOff);
            } else if (btnNextIndex == count-1) {
                btnNext.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgRightOff);
            } else {
                btnNext.setBackgroundDrawable(mBgCenterOff);
            }
        }

        btnLast.setPadding(0, mBtnPaddingTop, 0, mBtnPaddingBottom);
        btnNext.setPadding(0, mBtnPaddingTop, 0, mBtnPaddingBottom);

        mSelectedButtonIndex = btnNextIndex;
    }

    public int getSelectedButtonIndex() {
        return mSelectedButtonIndex;
    }

    public void setPushedButtonIndex(int index) {
        handleStateChange(mSelectedButtonIndex, index);
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListenerSegmentedButton listener) {
        mOnClickListenerExternal = listener;
    }

    public interface OnClickListenerSegmentedButton {
        public void onClick(int index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the SegmentedButton code as well?

Comment: @blipinsk hey i have posted SegmentedButton code !